# Is there a straightforward way to get all items in a vector after a specific index in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm writing a program that will receive commands from a python socket, and then execute them remotely. At first, I was going to use python on the whole project, but I decided to use C++, so I could learn a new language.
In Python, I have a script that looks like the following one:

```py
list = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5']
args1 = list[0]
args2 = list[1]
other = ' '.join(list[2:]) # 'arg3 arg4 arg5'
```

Now, I'm trying to translate this code to C++, but I'm not familiar with the language yet. So, my question is: Is there a straightforward way to get all items after a specific index in a `vector<string>` and join them in a single string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use iterators along with numeric lib

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**) {
  vector<string> v{"arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"};
  size_t index = 2;
  string merged = accumulate(v.begin() + index, v.end(), string(""));
  cout << merged; //arg3arg4
}
```

However this will not separate items with a blank space. For that you will have to add some extra code

```
...
accumulate(v.begin() + index, v.end(), string(""), 
           [](string& v, const string& item){
             return v.empty() ? item : v + ' ' + item;
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) which let's you specify where to insert and the range from the other container.

`str2.insert(str2.begin() + idx, str1.begin(), str1.end()`